# Dismiss the "Meet The Overflow" and Podcast Episode banners network-wide

Tags: bug, status-completed, notification-bar

There's a new banner shown on some of the technology Stack Exchange sites:

[image: The Overflow banner]

> Meet The Overflow, a newsletter by developers, for developers. Fascinating questions, illuminating answers, and entertaining links from around the web. [Learn more](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/01/introducing-overflow-newsletter-cassidy-williams?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=announcement-banner&utm_campaign=the-overflow-newsletter&utm_content=october-launch)

Every podcast episode now seems to be similarly advertised:

[image: Podcast banner]

> Podcast Episode #126: We chat GitHub Actions, fake boyfriends apps, and the dangers of Legacy code. [Listen now](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/).

When I dismiss these banners on e.g. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), I expect them to disappear from other sites as well. But that doesn't happen.

I regularly visit a lot of sites in the network, a permanent solution would be most welcome.

Comment: Yeah this starts to be super annoying, almost the same as spam emails. We get promotion stuff cluttering the page where we never asked for those at all.

Comment: TamperMonkey or GreaseMonkey, either is for you.

Comment: For the record, I still consider this a [tag:bug]: "Indicates a reproducible problem on the site that you believe is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error." It's both a mistake and a design error.

Comment: [Can we opt out of the banner announcing Stack Overflow Podcasts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390709/can-we-opt-out-of-the-banner-announcing-stack-overflow-podcasts)

Comment: Adblock works a treat

Comment: It *does* dismiss network wide... it just takes a minute.

Comment: @Catija wow, you're right. It took five minutes, actually, but that's definitely an improvement.

Comment: @Catija I still have the podcast banner on all sites, except MSE, where I dismissed it ~1 hour ago.

Comment: @pkamb It's not enabled here on MSE in the first place. Give dismissing it on another site a go and see if it sticks?

Comment: @AdamLear ok, new bug report then: podcast banners do *not* appear on MSE! Took about 3 minutes for the `X` to transfer from SO to other sites.

Comment: @pkamb It's not a bug, it's a deliberate decision not to show the banner on this site. (And a handful of others - MathOverflow and international SO sites).

Comment: @AdamLear the [*We’re rewarding the question askers & reputations are being recalculated!*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) banner IS being shown on MSE! Is it just Podcasts banners that aren't? But blog posts are?

Comment: @pkamb Which sites show which banner depends entirely on the banner. It's all configurable depending on the needs.

Comment: @AdamLear something seems to be wrong again, then. 30 minutes ago I dismissed the banner on MSE, but it's still there on SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're logged in, dismissing the banner should already apply network-wide - we set a cookie that is then picked up by Redis and the state cached based on your account id. I believe it does require another page load, though (for us to actually read the cookie and update the cache), and it might take a few minutes to propagate across all servers.

For anonymous users, dismissals are still per-site. We could probably switch to setting the cookie per second-level domain, but at the moment there are no plans or time to do so, if I'm entirely honest.

Comment: As a logged in SO / SE user who then visits a no-account site via HNQ or similar, we see the banner again. Probably expected, I guess that's an "anonymous user", but still weird.

Comment: @pkamb Ooh, good point. We can actually fix that, though. Would you mind writing up a separate bug report for that, please?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337356/notification-bar-podcast-etc-should-be-dismissed-on-sites-where-you-dont-ha

Comment: @pkamb Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: I'd vote for an option to disable it forever. I know it's just one click, but I really don't care for ads like _"We now integrate with Microsoft Teams, helping you to connect your internal knowledge base with your chat."_

Comment: I'm not the only one being annoyed by all the messages it shows: [Can we reserve the top bar announcements for actual site news?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338766/can-we-reserve-the-top-bar-announcements-for-actual-site-news) Please, prevent banner-blindness!

Answer (score 15):

It turns out this happened before with the [Net Neutrality banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298295/295232). It now happens again with the podcast with the new CEO, so I've modified the script and officially launched it on Stack Apps:

[Dismiss Announcement Banner](https://stackapps.com/q/8463/34061)

([GitHub link for direct installation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/dismiss-announcement-banner/dismiss-announcement-banner.user.js))

It uses cross-domain storage to remember if you have dismissed the banner, so every time you see one it's guaranteed to be one you've never seen before.