# Blog post announcing today's podcast is missing the link to the audio

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, podcast

There was a [new podcast announced on the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/19/podcast-a-few-of-our-favorite-things-about-react/) just now. There is a long description about what's happening in the podcast

...except it's missing the link to the actual podcast.

Can that mistake please be fixed?

(Also, what's the podcast number?)

Comment: Looks like they switched platform, so I'd say they don't want to get tons of bug reports from people who won't be happy about it. Anyway, looks like someone found it somehow: https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/how-would-you-react.

Comment: For some reason, they don't want to assign podcast episode numbers.

Comment: The link is in the RSS feed (available from the "Podcast" link at the top).

Comment: Why was today's podcast not given the usual [Banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334137/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed later on when some blog refactoring took place and Simplecast embeds became the standard for the new bits. Just following up here that it is done and the embed has a share link on there.