# Is there an option to opt-out from receiving network announcements?

Tags: support, notifications, announcements, preferences

From time to time I see notifications like the one below when browsing various Stack Exchange sites:

[image: Notification]

This is not a big deal, but I find them annoying for two reasons:

- in most cases, they do not mean anything to me
- look ugly on sites with the black top background (clearly a matter of taste)

I have checked the profile options and I only found options related to toolbar stickiness and e-mail preferences.

**Question:** Is there an option to opt-out from receiving network announcements?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. The real problem is that they abuse the top bar for vanity like the podcast instead of just critical network announcements such as scheduled down-times. There is a request to change that here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338766/can-we-reserve-the-top-bar-announcements-for-actual-site-news

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such option; [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338886/295232) is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) asking for it.

If you have an ad blocker like uBlock, you can add a rule which blocks them. They have an ID of `announcement-banner`, so the following should work (I haven't tested it since I already dismissed the banner):

```
###announcement-banner
```