# Let's remove the "Get updates..." notification

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, notifications

Recently this notification has started showing up quite repeatedly on Stack Exchange sites:

[image]

The problem is that it's not necessary, and even if it is, *it should not be showing up repeatedly*.

In just the last few months, these sorts of notifications have really risen on the Internet (think of YouTube's new notifications in the lower-left hand corner), and they are very stressful to deal with for three reasons:

1. They add *clutter* to the site's UI.
2. They are typically *not necessary or relevant* for the user.
3. Users should not have to dismiss the **same** notification *over and over again*.

All of these issues apply here.  Can we please get rid of this notification, and can we please keep the site's UI clean?  ***A clean, non-spammy UI is one of the reasons Stack Exchange got to be as popular as it is.***

---

**EDIT:**

As Mark Kirby pointed out in the comments, there was a very similar [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345674/295906) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295906).  That answer and my own post are suggesting two fairly similar things, with one difference:

The one answer suggests making the dismissal of this notification sitewide, and I suggest getting rid of it altogether.  In fact, I suggest never having notifications for things like this in general.  ***Clean*** notifications for *community activity and such* are great, but ***messy*** notifications for *UI features, news updates, and so on* are basically just clutter and an irritant.

So there is some similarity between the two suggestions, but there's a little bit of difference as well.

Comment: Î am pretty sure there was such an FR posted recently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network) Specifically this answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network

Comment: Sorry wrong link, this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345674/300925

Comment: Similar ideas, different location: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89045/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338886/282094 - I'm reluctant to assign this as a duplicate of one of those; looking for something better (closer).

Comment: I'm not going to touch the SE topic, but more generally it is driving me absolutely crazy that almost every site I go on now throws popups popups popups in my face. Subscribe to our newsletter, etc. Auto-playing videos. I thought we'd gotten rid of this nonsense after the 90s?? Argh!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you dismiss this on any site, it should not show up there again.

It is being shown to everyone right now (once per site) to publicize a new feature that was released earlier this week.

After an introductory period, we will switch it to only showing for new users.

If you dismiss it and it returns on the same site, please let me know.

Comment: I have had to dismiss it multiple times on my Super User profile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I just now got it again on SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.  It seems to go away for the same site within the same browser session, but seems to have issues between browser sessions.  I'm not sure if there's anything else needed to reproduce it, but in my case just now, I was logged in to the same account in both scenarios.

Comment: Can you please check your console tab and see if any errors, and network tab and see what call made when you click to dismiss? We have double checked, should not be session based, should update flag on your user that will prevent it from showing again.

Comment: I'll try to do it next time it shows up.

Comment: All right, I’ll bite: *why* do you want it to keep showing for new users rather than getting rid of it completely? Even for new users, there are no such popovers for the dozens of other features of the UI (or at least I hope so, as it would create an ungodly mess); do you consider the follow feature particularly confusing? If so, wouldn’t it be more effective to explain it in a new user tutorial, or something?

Comment: That is, even though the follow feature as such is awsome, you should see by now from the many reactions and votes that the popover is universally regarded as an extreme annoyance. Now, I thought the official SE policy was to *be more welcoming* towards new users, not to *deter them with extreme annoyance*.

Comment: @YaakovEllis okay I just reproduced the issue with Firefox 74.0 (64-bit) on Win 10. On the site where I clicked cross sign to dismiss, network tab shows nothing and the only warning in console was "Request to access cookie or storage on “<URL>” was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is enabled". Extensions enabled are only DevTools ADB and Snap Links

Comment: @gnat most likely your ad blocker. It should make an Ajax call to save that you saw it. (call is to main domain, no idea why would be blocked)

Comment: @YaakovEllis I don't use ad blockers. I heard though that Firefox recently instroduced stricter handling of stuff that looks like tracking / ads, so maybe it somehow tripped browser's "suspicions" (FWIW I am not going to fiddle with browser defaults in case if these are indeed a reason)