# Don't tell users to vote for their own post

Tags: feature-request, bug, tooltips

Yesterday, there were new voting tool-tips added:

- [What's the reasoning behind the vote button tooltips having changed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349527/707129)

I came across this today:

> [image]

I can't upvote my own answer, so can the tooltip not say this?

Maybe it can show:

> - your post has a score of *x*

Poem for [*Mithical*'s contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349555/a-meta-se-poetry-contest-write-poems-win-rep):

> I recently came across a post
>
> And I said to myself holy ghost
>
> It's mine, that's Daniil
>
> But then I stood still
>
> Why vote for myself? I never boast

Comment: This is consistent with how the text was before - it still instructed you how to vote. It's also referenced a lot - people asking "Why was my post downvoted" are frequently instructed to look at the description of the downvote button by hovering. Perhaps the action instruction ("Downvote..."/"Upvote...") can be omitted but the qualification should stay. In fact, might need to be *more* prominent as voting is quite misunderstood in general.