# Podcast advertisement banner does not hide permanently after clicking "Listen Now"

Tags: bug, notification-bar, announcements, podcast

Today a new top notification bar appeared on Stack Overflow to advertise the podcast:

[image: podcast advertisement]

When I click "Listen Now", the link opens in the background **and the banner hides itself** on SO.

But if I refresh the page on SO, the banner is back!

If the banner is going to hide, it should hide permanently after taking action on the podcast advertisement.

The banner *does* hide permanently after clicking the "X".

---

Related:

- [Dismiss the "Meet The Overflow" and Podcast Episode banners network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334137/dismiss-the-meet-the-overflow-and-podcast-episode-banners-network-wide)
- [Can we reserve the top bar announcements for actual site news?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338766/can-we-reserve-the-top-bar-announcements-for-actual-site-news)

Comment: That's how all the banners work. The problem is not the behaviour, but that they're used for stuff that isn't a major announcement like the podcast.

Answer (score 3):

That is how the banners are supposed to work.  The "X" is there for those who want to permanently dismiss the banner (sometimes this doesn't work - see [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/8463/dismiss-announcement-banner) made by Glorfindel over at [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com) if you have that problem).